# set img as background

Tags: html, css, background-image

I would like to know how I can set my `background` as an image using

```
<img src="" alt="sample" width="480" height="500" border="0">
```

I know I don't have an image name that is because I'm picking an image from a dropdown menu.
My problem is how do I integrate the code about to be displayed as a `background image`.

This is what I need to integrate it to.

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Generally you'd set an image as a background using CSS, not using an `img` tag.

Comment: the way I want to do it so I can change background image at any given time and this is the img src that works to change image

Comment: You can change CSS styling too.

Comment: You can use javascript or jQuery to change the background image once the dropdown is selected or changed.  Look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `background` property doesn't apply to `img` tag, because `img` tag as already a `src` to use an image of course, so if you want to apply a `background`, then use some element like `div`, applying then properties in CSS.

If you want to pick that from dropdown you can use classes for that using JS

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $('.container').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.red {
  background: red
}
.green {
  background: green
}
.blue {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="opt1">red</option>
  <option value="opt2">green</option>
  <option value="opt3">blue</option>
</select>
<div id="opt1" class="container red"></div>
<div id="opt2" class="container green"></div>
<div id="opt3" class="container blue"></div>
```

Comment: is it possible to make this work   background: lightgrey url("img src="" alt="sample"")

Comment: nop that's invalid CSS, you can't have a html tag inside a CSS property.

Comment: but you can have an image inside `background`, using `background:url()`, something like: `background:url("//lorempixel.com/500/500")`, I just used colors for the sake of easiness on the demo

Comment: I appreciate your help